# flask-sqlalchemy read/write endpoints

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, amazon-rds, flask-restful

I'm using `flask`/`flask-sqlalchemy`/`flask-restx` to build small micro-services; I'm using AWS Aurora with MySQL as database tech. Aurora conveniently provides separate read/write endpoints for the db and routes traffic/connections to either the master or to the read-replicas depending on what endpoint is used.

Is there a way to discriminate the session URL that is used by `flask-sqlalchemy` by configuring two database URLs in the `app.config` and using one or the other endpoint depending on whether the `get` method is used versus of the `post`, `put` and `delete` ones?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to separate Master Slave (DB read / writes) in Flask Sqlalchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12093956/how-to-separate-master-slave-db-read-writes-in-flask-sqlalchemy)