# what is the best practice for Python - SQLAlchemy to connect to Master-Slave Databases (replication)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi, replication, master-slave

I am using "Python-SQLAlchemy" for the first time.

Mostly I used Nodejs . In Node.js eco-system , the ORM "Sequelize" has a support for replication (write in the Master DB , read from multiple Slave DB)

is there any best practice for "SQLAlchemy" to process read queries by Slave Database and all write queries on Master Database

Comment: I would say this is typically realized on the database level, rather than the application level. The application should not be aware of any database setup. For Postgres databases for example, I’ve seen PgPool II being used in critical applications. I assume there are equivalents for other databases.

Comment: For MySQL you have ProxySQL; if you want to [mimic it in SQLAlchemy you're going to have to do multiple binds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12093956/how-to-separate-master-slave-db-read-writes-in-flask-sqlalchemy) as far as I know. Not a recommended solution as it will require you to manually tweak a lot of things.

Comment: both of the answers (by JarroVGIT and  MatsLindh ) are quite helpful. I never had idea about these tools like PgPool II or ProxySQL . now I understand the point " database level, rather than the application level" . thanks all